# Flutter - iOS build using Bitrise

Tags: ios, flutter, bitrise, auto-build

I am using Bitrise to generate iOS build of my flutter project. I have follow [this](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/en/getting-started/getting-started-with-flutter-apps.html#deploying-a-flutter-app) steps to configure workflow. It shows me error like this. [image]Can you please guide what's wrong here and how to fix this error.

Answer (score 2):

In the xcode-archive step, these values are pre-configured as environment variables. You need to add these variables either in Bitrise UI or bitrise.yml file:

```
app:
 envs:
- opts:
    is_expand: false
  BITRISE_FLUTTER_PROJECT_LOCATION: "."
- opts:
    is_expand: false
  BITRISE_IOS_LOCATION: ios/Runner.xcworkspace
- opts:
    is_expand: false
  BITRISE_SCHEME: Runner
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help. Here is another way to solve above issue.

Answer (score 1):

For above error we can edit input variables in "Xcode Archive & Export for iOS" step and give proper path of your xcworkspace and name of your schema.

[image: Check below image for reference]